# How to split Unicode string in non-Alphanumeric characters with regular expression?

Tags: regex, delphi

I want to split a string that contains unicode words on non_Alphanumeric characters such as space, CRLF and etc.

For example:

```
AStr := 'امین Bob(Alice)';
```

I'm looking for a regular expression to split `AStr` into a list of below:

```
امین
Bob
Alice
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and where did you fail?

Comment: I was thinking the `[\W]+` which stand for non-Alphanumeric consider unicode characters but it is detected unicode character as non-Alphanumeric.

Comment: Take a look at `\b` which matches word boundaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading [Regex Tutorial - Unicode Characters and Properties: Unicode Categories](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category) I realized that the answer is:

```
AnArray := TRegEx.Split(ADataStr, '[^\p{L}\p{N}]+');
```

Comment: I'd add `\p{M}`, as otherwise you might cut legal names like `Chloë` into `Chloe` and `¨` for [combined characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character).